# TO_TIMESTAMP in Insert Statement String

Tags: java, oracle

I'm constructing a Oracle insert statement in Java and I have the below timestamp that I need to insert.  The below works, but I would like to make it more dynamic.  Is there another way to do this besides hardcoding the TO_TIMESTAMP in my insert String?

```
String sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO TABLE (date_create);
sqlStmt += "TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-03-17 21:43:58.000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')";
```

Comment: What db library are you using, JDBC?  Add it as a statement parameter.

Comment: You could use a `PreparedStatement` and bind a `java.sql.Timestamp` instance.

Comment: I'm just writing a script to create a file of insert statements to run directly in a Oracle Query window via the Database Software (SQL Developer).

Answer (score 0):

both java and sql developer allows you to use bind variables.

```
sqlStmt = 'insert into table(date_create) values (:date_create1)'
```

Now all you need to do is to create a timestamp parameter date_create1 and pass it in.